# Solve $x \times x = 1$ in a field?

Tags: field-theory

If I am in an arbitrary field and I have $x \times x = 1$, does this imply $x = 1$ or $x = -1$?

I feel like it should and I have been trying to prove it but I can't get there.  Or maybe there is an obscure field where this is not true.

Thanks

Comment: You can factor $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, which implies $x-1=0$ or $x+1=0$ since you can't multiply nonzero elements and get $0$ in a domain.

Answer (score 8):

In fact, the equation $x^2=1$ has at most $2$ solutions in a field, so the only solutions are $x=1$ and $x=-1$. If the characteristic of the field is $2$, we only have one solution namely $x=1$

Answer (score 4):

In any field (even a non commutative field) $(x+1)(x+(-1))=x^2-x+x-1=x^2-1$, therefore
$$x^2-1\iff x=-1\text{ or }x=1$$
If the characteristc of the field is $2$ both solutions are the same.

This reasoning also works in any integral domain.

Comment: Exactly. Consider an element $a$ in an integral domain. ___If___ it has a square root at all, that is if the equation $x^2=a$ has a solution, say $r$, then the square root is unique _up to a sign_. Because then the equation can be written $x^2=r^2$ or $x^2-r^2=0$ which leads to $(x+r)(x-r)=0$ which can only happen if $x=-r$ or $x=r$. We can denote these numbers $\pm\sqrt{a}$ in this case. It is possible that $r=-r$ or $2r=0$ if either $2=0$ or $r=0$ in the ring in question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen huh, how can you denote thes numbers $\pm\sqrt a$? Which is which?

Comment: @djechlin We do not know which is which. But one is the other's opposite, and vice versa. This notation I have seen for example with complex numbers, as in the formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{d}}{2a}$. We do not need to have a convention for choosing a "principal" value among the two.

Comment: @djechlin: Basically, what we can do is to define $\sqrt{x}$ to be a (partial) function that returns one of the square-roots of $x$ if it exists, and be undefined otherwise. Then indeed if $x$ is a square then its square-roots must be precisely $\{\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}\}$.

Comment: @user21820 which square root does it return?

Comment: @djechlin: Precisely my point is that it does not matter! From the point of view of the field itself (meaning first-order definable), the roots are indistinguishable. If you don't get what I mean, feel free to clarify, as this is more related to logic even though relevant to *Jeppe*'s initial comment.

Comment: @user21820 so it's not a function if it's not clear what it outputs? It would just be a relation then.

Comment: @djechlin: I'm afraid you do not understand functions. A function does **not** have to be describable. There are uncountably many functions from the naturals into the naturals, **even though** there are only countably many of them that we can describe. If you have any further queries about this, perhaps you should come to the [logic chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) where I can explain to you in detail; this comment thread is not the place for it.